# Laravel, can't retrieve AJAX data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am having trouble with Laravel, in particular, with getting AJAX request data from my JavaScript but I am able to make a connection between my controller and my front-end by testing with returning a string and it works, but I just can't get my data from the front end.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'foo',
    food: 'something'
}

function sendMsg(obj) {

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
};

request.open("POST","create/new.php");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","x-www-form-encoded");
request.send(encodeData(obj));

}

sendMsg(obj);
```

The encodeData function basically just encodes my object to a form encoded string.

This is my route:

```
Route::post('create/{new}', 'AppController@createNew');
```

And my controller:

```
public function createNew() {
    $input = Input::all();
    return $input; 
}
```

The response I get is an empty array and I also tried using:

```
Input::get('name');
```

But it doesn't work either.

I checked the request header that is sent to laravel in dev tools and the post body is populated with the encoded string I want to pass to my controller but I just can't seem to retrieved it in my controller. Has anybody experience this before? Any insight and advice would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit: added the data object in JavaScript part so my code is more complete.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not sending any input data - so why would you expect Input::all() to not be an empty array?

Comment: I am but I just left it out in the code above so the code will be brief. I am sending just a simple object just to learn how Laravel works.

Comment: what webserver are you using?  Are you sure your request is getting to Laravel and not being intercepted by a rule on the webserver?

Comment: Why not try just `return 'Hello';` from `createNew()` and make sure that you're set up correctly?

Comment: I am using WAMP so the server is apache. I am not sure though if the request is really getting to Laravel, is there a way to test that? I can however send data succesfully from my controller to JavaScript but I can't get it the other way around

Comment: @Leng I tried that too, which I received successfully, so there is that connection between my controller and JavaScript.

Comment: @dnlSand what's in `encodeData`?  Is it definitely returning something that can be posted?

Comment: @msturdy The encodeData function I have just encodes the object I have to a URI component so it can be sent to the server. I tested this function by itself and it does return the encoded string that I need to pass to my controller.

Comment: @dnlSand  it's your Content-Type header... check out my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the right `Content-Type` header in your JS.

It should be as follows:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: @msturdy OMG! It worked! Thank you so much! Oh man, it was something I didn't even considered to be reason causing the data to not reach my controller. If I'm not mistaken, if the wrong content type header is sent, the request is ignored, is that what happened? Thank you again!

Comment: @dnlSand haha, glad to help, took me ages to spot! You were telling the server to expect something that doesn't exist (as far as I am aware), so I guess it was just ignoring the body of the request!

Comment: Solved my problem also! Thanks!